# Online code viewer for a whole directory

Tags: c++, php-codebrowser

I have a C++ project that I place, using a cron task, in a given directory under the web root.

How can I add a web interface so that when users click something like "Browse source code" have a nice interface rather than seeing the standard directory content returned by Apache ?
I know either traditional code viewers associated to revision control programs or "beautifiers" for single files, but I can't get (or, I think, I can't guess the right Google keyword) an online code browser that works over a simple directory (recursively obviously).

[image]

Comment: The best web Code Browser I know is [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/), but it is Java-based.

Comment: @myaut: thank you, but I am looking on something much more simpler.. Something similar to this (in the output): http://web.media.mit.edu/~vyzo/srcb/doc/index.html

Comment: That link is 404 btw..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/network/access/ ?

It shows links to classes/structs/enums.

[image: Woboq Code Browser Directory Index]